# Using transactions within Rails around_create callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, transactions, callback

I've got a situation where I need to 'do_this' after 'foo' has been created successfully and 'do_that' when 'do_this' has been executed without errors, like so:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  around_create do |foo, block|
    transaction do
      block.call # invokes foo.save

      do_this!
      do_that!
    end
  end

  protected

  def do_this!
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if something_fails
  end

  def do_that!
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if something_else_fails
  end

end
```

And the entire transaction should be rolled back in case one of them fails.

The problem however is, that 'foo' is always persisted even if 'do_this' or 'do_that' fails. What gives?

Answer (score 4):

you don't need to do this, if you return false to a callback, it will trigger a rollback.  The simplest way to code what you want is like this

```
after_save :do_this_and_that

def do_this_and_that
  do_this && do_that
end

def do_this
  # just return false here if something fails. this way,
  # it will trigger a rollback since do_this && do_that
  # will be evaluated to false and do_that will not be called
end

def do_that
  # also return false here if something fails to trigger
  # a rollback
end
```

Comment: So you're saying that there's no need to wrap any code inside a transaction block to successfully do a rollback on errors?

Comment: @velu did you confirm that?